# Antidepressants and side effects

Tags: side-effects, medications

There is a friend of mine who takes antidepressants regularly, and now he is kind of addicted to them. Will this cause any health problems for him? How about any long term side effects?

Comment: Do you have some specific concerns? I mean this is really common problem and many large institutions (ie. MayoClinic, NHS) have detailed descriptions of the side effects of each antidepressant drug. This information is fairly easily accessed online.

Comment: ["If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](http://health.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) There are actually entire books on this topic.